# Android Application -gives error in registration, however data is still inserted into database

Tags: java, android, json

I have in the process of developing a registration app using Android Studios, however once users try to register the application just says error in registration and the CatLog does not give any error, as well as when debugging the app, I still get no errors.

Please can you help and tell me where I am going wrong as the code is correct as it was working couple of months ago, however since I have returned from holiday it just says "Error occurred in registration".

User data gets entered into the database however it does not allow the user to move ont to the next activity as it says "Error occurred in registration". Please can you help or advise?

LogCat

```
> SERVER: Hello Rylan,
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: You have successfully registered to our service.
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: Regards,
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: Admin.
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER:
    2016-01-06 12:25:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
    2016-01-06 12:25:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1452083131 w17sm8434668wmw.15 - gsmtp
    2016-01-06 12:25:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    2016-01-06 12:25:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection w17sm8434668wmw.15 - gsmtp
    {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"Rylan","lname":"Clark","email":"rylanclark189@hotmail.com","uname":"clarkR","uid":"568d07af2d6718.72308438","created_at":"2016-01-06 12:25:19"}}
01-06 12:22:14.548    2561-2914/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 2016-01-06 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

> The LogCat shows that the data is inserted into the database as it says a success message, however the application just says "Error occurred in registration" once I register user. As the LogCat confirms that the user has received an email and their registration details are saved in the database. Please can you help and advise, I have checked the code and it looks like everything is correct.

Registger.Java

```
public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    ImageButton btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        /**
         * Defining all layout items
         **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Registerbtn);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/



        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }


    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occurred in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

UserFunction.Java

```
//URL of the PHP API

        private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Register_api/";

    private static String register_tag = "register";

    /**
             * Function to  Register
             **/
            public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
                // Building Parameters
                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
                return json;
            }
```

Jsonpasar.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cloud_contacts";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname); // UserName
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("uname", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }






    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }


    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

I have tried ever single trick in the book, however. I am still unable to resolve the issue. Could you please help and advice.

Comment: your if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { is wron just check there are two if conditions. Just check once

Comment: can you add your json response after registration

Comment: The application just says error in registration when user tries to register, however the registered user receives an email and the data is inputted into the database. When I try to login it allows me to login with the new user registered details. I dont understand why it says error in registration, even though the user details are entered into the database.

Comment: yes its because of your if condition please check else part of that if condition

Comment: I have tried to use this as well if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

        String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
            pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

            registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

            /**
             * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
             **/

            UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
            logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
            /**
             * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
             * Launch Registered screen
             **/

            Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

            /**
             * Close all views before launching Registered screen
             **/
            registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(registered);


            finish();
        }

        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
        }
        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
        }

    }


    else{
        pDialog.dismiss();

        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occurred in registration");
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

use above code and check.

Comment: you can also use in if json.has(KEY_SUCCESS)

Comment: Once I have done this now I get error message. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com..Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:211)
            at com..Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:171)